# Java Spring JPA conversion to myBatis

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, mybatis, spring-mybatis

For homework I was asked to implement myBatis. However, I already started all of my project using Spring Data JPA. And so I need to translate JPA query to myBatis. here is the code in JPA:
[follow this link for the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbsnW.png)

```java
@Repository
public interface VoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Vote, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT NEW com.example.polls.model.ChoiceVoteCount(v.choice.id, count(v.id)) FROM Vote v WHERE v.poll.id in :pollIds GROUP BY v.choice.id")
    List<ChoiceVoteCount> countByPollIdInGroupByChoiceId(@Param("pollIds") List<Long> pollIds);

    @Query("SELECT NEW com.example.polls.model.ChoiceVoteCount(v.choice.id, count(v.id)) FROM Vote v WHERE v.poll.id = :pollId GROUP BY v.choice.id")
    List<ChoiceVoteCount> countByPollIdGroupByChoiceId(@Param("pollId") Long pollId);

    @Query("SELECT v FROM Vote v where v.user.id = :userId and v.poll.id in :pollIds")
    List<Vote> findByUserIdAndPollIdIn(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("pollIds") List<Long> pollIds);

    @Query("SELECT v FROM Vote v where v.user.id = :userId and v.poll.id = :pollId")
    Vote findByUserIdAndPollId(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("pollId") Long pollId);

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(v.id) from Vote v where v.user.id = :userId")
    long countByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);

    @Query("SELECT v.poll.id FROM Vote v WHERE v.user.id = :userId")
    Page<Long> findVotedPollIdsByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I'm trying to use these myBatis imports instead:

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Delete;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Insert;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Update;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
```

Comment: MyBatis uses SQL not JPQL so you will have to write all these in the Select annotation

Comment: @Simon Martinelli Thanks yes I see what you mean. But the problem for me here is the first two query contain constructors NEW. I have no idea how to do the equivalent using SQL (myBatis)

Comment: There isn't but you don't need that. This is JPA specific to get result as a DTO. With MyBatis you can have any result class

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Could you give me a sample answer for the first query for example? I was reading from this page but still not clear. https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548470/mybatis-mapping-for-select-query

Comment: thanks a bunch! I'm still not sure (mostly because myBatis use only SQL but here there are constructors), for now I will probably sleep on it, think it over a few days. I'm looking at the pojo (Vote, ChoiceVoteCount) too